# Attach QDockWidget to QWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget, qdockwidget

I don't understand from the documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-dockwidgets-example.html) whether a QDockWidget can be attached to a QWidget.

I m trying to create a new additional window (a QWidget) and I would like to attach to it a Dock, but when I pass the QWidget as a parent, the Dock shows up in the QMainWindow

Comment: `QDockWidget`s can be docked only into `QMainWindow`